# How do I make the control handles of a node visible in Affinity Designer 1.7?

Tags: vector, affinity-designer

[image: A picture of Affinity Designer interface with a yellow change with one node selected with the node tool.]

Hello, I am trying to select a node on this vector shape so that I can extend the control handles and then make this sharp point a rounded one. I have read the manual, but clicking and dragging with the node tool isn't exposing the handles for me, rather it just moves the node around slightly. [image: node moved] This is the reference that I used: https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/index.html?page=pages/Tools/tools_node.html?title=Node%20Tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods for node conversion between angular and bézier curves:

**1. Via Node toolbar Node Convert button above main canvas area:**

With your given angular node or nodes selected, choose **Convert to Smooth** from Node toolbar above (the icon looks like a curved bézier node) to convert your nodes.

[image]

The bézier handles will appear and the curve will appropriately bend out as expected.

[image]

**2. One-click on Line Segment with Node tool:**

With the Node Selection tool (white arrow) simply click on a straight line segment and pull - this will instantly become a bézier curve which you are live editing - super-simple and elegant.

[image]

Hope this helps.